# Get subscribers who have opened one or more email in last 5 email deliveries

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views, email-tracking

I have a requirement where i need to fetch subscribers who have opened at least one email in the last 5 emails delivered to them. Is there any way to achieve this. 
I have tried Data Views like _Subsribers and _Sent.

Comment: Please provide what you've tested already and what are the problems/errors you are facing.

Comment: Answer: Yes. Question can be closed or needs to be edited a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT 
r.SubscriberKey,
j.EmailName, 
s.EventDate as SentDate, 
o.EventDate as OpenDate, 
FROM [YOUR DATA EXTENSION]r LEFT JOIN _Sent s ON r.SubscriberKey= s.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN _Job as j ON s.JobID = j.JobID 
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON s.JobID = o.JobID and s.ListID = o.ListID and s.BatchID = o.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID and o.IsUnique = 1
WHERE j.EmailName = 'first email name'
OR j.EmailName = 'second email name'
OR j.EmailName = 'third email name'
OR j.EmailName = 'forth email name'
OR j.EmailName = 'fifth email name'
```

Comment: The emphasis on this answer is **LIKE** this. There is no timing or last 5 jobs or something involved to be dynamic. This answer is static

Comment: You are right @Johannes Schapdick

Comment: Thanks for your response @Duicug. We are not checking any particular email delivery. Last 5 emails could be any of the emails in marketing cloud anf then we need to check if anyone of those last 5 deliveries has been opened. Currently i don't know feasibility of this.